# Download the SVF data using Design Automation API (DA)

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to convert inventor.ipt file to SVF data, and download the SVF data using Design Automation API (DA).
Referring to the following blog, instead of Appbundles, create the iLogicVb file shown below and upload it　in the same bucket of inventor.ipt.
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/speed-viewable-generation-when-using-design-automation-inventor
The execution result of workkitem is "status": "success", but nothing is output to output.zip.

What is wrong?

```
uploaded file name is
Question_SVFinput.iLogicVb


' Get AutoCAD Inventor object
Dim inventorApplication As Inventor.Application = ThisApplication

' Get the documentation (if necessary, use the appropriate method to get the documentation)
Dim doc As Document = ThisDoc.Document

'Output folder path

Dim docDir As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ThisDoc.Document.FullFileName)
Dim filePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(docDir, "output.zip")
Dim outputFolderPath As String = filePath

' Log trace
'iLogicVb.Automation.LogTrace("**Saving SVF")
Try
    ' Get TranslatorAddIn object
    Dim oAddin As TranslatorAddIn = inventorApplication.ApplicationAddIns.ItemById("{C200B99B-B7DD-4114-A5E9-6557AB5ED8EC}")

    'Create a TranslationContext object
    Dim oContext As TranslationContext = inventorApplication.TransientObjects.CreateTranslationContext()
    oContext.Type = IOMechanismEnum.kFileBrowseIOMechanism

    'Create NameValueMap object
    Dim oOptions As NameValueMap = inventorApplication.TransientObjects.CreateNameValueMap()
    Dim oData As DataMedium = inventorApplication.TransientObjects.CreateDataMedium()

    'Set output file path
    oData.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(outputFolderPath, "result.collaboration")

    'Set SVF options
    If oAddin.get_HasSaveCopyAsOptions(doc, oContext, oOptions) Then
        oOptions.Value("EnableExpressTranslation") = False
        oOptions.Value("SVFFileOutputDir") = outputFolderPath
        oOptions.Value("ExportFileProperties") = True
        oOptions.Value("ObfuscateLabels") = False
    End If

    ' Execute the SaveCopyAs method
    oAddin.SaveCopyAs(doc, oContext, oOptions, oData)
    
    ' Output trace information
    'iLogicVb.Automation.LogTrace("SVF can be exported.")
    'iLogicVb.Automation.LogTrace("** Saved SVF as " & oData.FileName)

Catch ex As Exception
    ' Output error log
    'iLogicVb.Automation.LogError("********Export to format SVF failed: " & ex.Message)

End Trytype here
```

```
//This is written so that it can be executed using a Google Sheets macro.
//Activity is defined as below.

/////////////////////////////////////////

function SVFcreateActivity() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var okikae=sheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var aa = sheet.getRange("D14").getValue()+"Result.ipt"; 
  var aaid = sheet.getRange("D29").getValue(); 
     
  // リクエストのオプションを設定
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + okikae
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      id: aaid,
      commandLine: [
        "$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /i \"$(args[InventorDoc].path)\" /s \"$(args[iLogicVb].path)\""
      ],
      parameters: {
        InventorDoc: {
          verb: "get",
          description: "Input Inventor part file",
          localName: aa
        },
        iLogicVb: {
          verb: "get",
          description: "Use iLogicVb",
          localName: "SVFinput.iLogicVb"
        },
        OutputIam: {
           zip: true,
           ondemand: false,
           optional: true,
           localName: "output.zip",
           verb: "post"
        },
//        Outputipt: {
//          localName: aa,
//          verb: "put"
//        }
      },
      engine: "Autodesk.Inventor+2023",
      appbundles: [],
      settings: {},
      description: "Change param and inventor Model"
    })
  };

  // APIエンドポイント
  var pppath = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/activities";

  // HTTPリクエストを送信
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pppath, options);
  var responseBody = response.getContentText();

  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log(responseBody);

 // JSONパースしてオブジェクトに変換
  var responseObject = JSON.parse(responseBody);
  // idの値を抽出
  var id = responseObject.id;
  sheet.getRange("C32").setValue(id);

}
```

```
The workitem report looks like this:
///////////////////////////////////////////////

[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Job information:
{
  "CommandLine": [
    "$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /i \"$(args[InventorDoc].path)\" /s \"$(args[iLogicVb].path)\""
  ],
  "Settings": {
    "dasOpenNetwork": {
      "value": "true",
      "isEnvironmentVariable": true
    }
  },
  "Id": "f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513",
  "ActivityId": "kNAV4o1UQAg2Y2ZzBBvIGkSRJVNqs9aE.act202311221445+V1",
  "EngineId": "Autodesk.Inventor_2023!39",
  "Apps": [],
  "BoundArguments": {
    "InventorDoc": {
      "localName": "h34w36Result.ipt",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:F68kJ3dbu5a1AI2H7p8JKtif49c="
    },
    "iLogicVb": {
      "localName": "SVFinput.iLogicVb",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:ojBPacq/dcM+wl2uhLO688nn2/8="
    },
    "OutputIam": {
      "zip": true,
      "localName": "output.zip",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:j5sFuqc2Iakd5eea77012DTzHa4=",
      "verb": "put"
    }
  },
  "Quotas": {
    "limitProcessingTimeSec": 900,
    "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 500
  }
}
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Folder "T:\Aces\Jobs\f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513\output.zip" has been created.
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Starting work item f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Start download phase.
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/cb98f656-3dcd-497f-9da6-5142299cab9c?region=US'
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/40b6c64a-3298-4f10-9a90-9b67448bfd2c?region=US'
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/40b6c64a-3298-4f10-9a90-9b67448bfd2c?region=US,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513\SVFinput.iLogicVb,BytesDownloaded=2131,Duration=141ms
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/cb98f656-3dcd-497f-9da6-5142299cab9c?region=US,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513\h34w36Result.ipt,BytesDownloaded=100352,Duration=298ms
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] End download phase successfully.
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513\h34w36Result.ipt" /s "T:\Aces\Jobs\f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513\SVFinput.iLogicVb"]
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Start script phase.
[11/22/2023 05:46:02] Start Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : InventorCoreConsole.exe: 25.0.18300.0, 15-e376d5d
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Starting Inventor Server.
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to get Inventor Server version in use.
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Inventor Server version is 27, 10, 20801, 0000.
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Inventor Server version is 2023 or newer
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Started Inventor Server 2023.1 (Build 271208000, 208) (27, 10, 20801, 0000)
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/22/2023 05:46:03]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/22/2023 05:46:03]     iLogic Plugin: initializing...
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting up iLogicLogLevelTo: Warn
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opening document: T:\Aces\Jobs\f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513\h34w36Result.ipt Invisible mode: False
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opened
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/22/2023 05:46:03] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Executing 'RunExternalRule' method on Automation object.
[11/22/2023 05:46:05] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Performing iLogic diagnostics...
[11/22/2023 05:46:05] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : End of iLogic diagnostics...
[11/22/2023 05:46:05] CoreConsole Dispose start
[11/22/2023 05:46:05] CoreConsole ReleaseAll start
[11/22/2023 05:46:05] CoreConsole ReleaseAll end
[11/22/2023 05:46:05] CoreConsole Dispose end
[11/22/2023 05:46:05] CoreConsole exiting (0)
[11/22/2023 05:46:06] End Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[11/22/2023 05:46:06] End script phase.
[11/22/2023 05:46:06] Start upload phase.
[11/22/2023 05:46:06] Zipping directory T:\Aces\Jobs\f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513\output.zip as T:\Aces\Jobs\f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513\output.zip.zip.
[11/22/2023 05:46:06] Uploading 'T:\Aces\Jobs\f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513\output.zip.zip': verb - 'PUT', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/b0c35cfc-91d4-4bd2-9082-fdd233052db8?region=US'
[11/22/2023 05:46:06] End upload phase successfully.
[11/22/2023 05:46:07] Job finished with result Succeeded
[11/22/2023 05:46:07] Job Status:
{
  "status": "success",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/kNAV4o1UQAg2Y2ZzBBvIGkSRJVNqs9aE/f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=90000&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEM7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIBGSUFE0hf61hbK2rxL6NYiLoGUVvzwTGKWlKePPiPIrAiEAwnxXFai0K2HdFjhpNgdUFo7fAOyFeY%2Bq%2F7Rq2BoSDUEqgAMIJhAEGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDIowQsfVy5cYRHfFHSrdAvGdbTRmza4sP2aAC0xcyS4W5YZRkjilFTuvsZkLX9zvKl4tiYeeEMwQWXDVOFhZqeR164TTqLUkfV1FBvO0F9vaMg3Eqzebaq2AJY1Y7%2FkfAQeEOGkUbIQ5w1iOlcs7vjNy1pTbzeSZHg8xB8HWpkMnnJXXSVRRg0b%2BXhlwaaDGH%2Bmr1zoY60RZcVfzpQuCU1XGhsS%2FH6JgN%2BKzQ64%2FUsUbfB6coRQfew0yABOP3v4iYRcZ22p1iuBoLCrCZX6JeqaX83GY60JMNnwB9LLDhmyu8hlxONgO1oDkJ9Kt3jciJXAM4cGSFm%2BGwO0U4rG9PoAfpqUx0XcAUhJIk7DVaSgni4v9wwR91RPV8VSvXvFhUGZDiRUFD%2FhsSJNXlNIwqdKgt0iHQOhoSVzCh2RQ9D7Y1d9wMHAYLKrRyyhpTalrjLmWeDLc1JWZxOWuuqFfI6s5N9YzQPmSo8F8U0swn5n2qgY6ngHEi%2FcyrFSRvVxKclpblmrPxZi2CWVekFokNXHpCqDfcYpB%2BzA5LMDlt692f5K2QChSbg4fI1dyDcmrZabScxi1Qoqi4V2xDkWguM3atZoDhd2DtyzmV3FVXEf6lRx%2FCxl3VIiWFRi72n0rJdUsfd2EMyh6KZ9KE9jQYhJtO0%2B9rniDHy650GfYG8Tbzk5ss62k0pFR64%2BpAnUqpXDlKg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3J7N4LU74%2F20231122%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231122T054602Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=eec1e59f2b519727a6626207add78977cca7e17febd73a0a63411d53dc074ebb",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2023-11-22T05:46:02.2508179Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-11-22T05:46:02.3674537Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2023-11-22T05:46:02.8225123Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2023-11-22T05:46:06.592558Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2023-11-22T05:46:06.8530583Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 102483,
    "bytesUploaded": 22
  },
  "id": "f6fd35376a0745f6be05676108684513"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to provide more information about how you set up your **activity** and the full report of the **work item**.

If you are using the [sample website](https://aps-run-ilogic.autodesk.io/) that is pointed out by [this blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/quick-tests-using-ilogic), then you should keep the [**iLogic** code](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-run-ilogic/blob/main/iLogicRules/DA4I-SVF.iLogicVb) exactly as-is, because it expects the results in the `outputFiles` folder.

Comment: In the question area, I added　write activity　notation and the full report of the work item.